# Flask SQLAlchemy & Flask-Security-too

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-security

I am having an issue with Flask-Security-too and SQLAlchemy. In the below example I can create a user, once the user has been created I would then like to create thread, with a one to many relationship. When I pass the user object in to the query, I receive the following error message;

> sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding
> parameter 1 - probably unsupported type. [SQL: INSERT INTO thread
> (title, user_id) VALUES (?, ?)] [parameters: ('NewThread', <User 1>)]
> (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5)

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_security import SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, Security

db = SQLAlchemy()
security = Security()


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    db.init_app(app)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secretkey__'
    app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT'] = 'secretsalt__'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

class RolesUsers(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    role_id = db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id'))

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=True)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    fs_uniquifier = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    roles = db.relationship(
        'Role', secondary='roles_users', backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
    threads = db.relationship('Thread', backref='author', lazy=True)

class Role(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)

class Thread(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security.init_app(app, user_datastore)

# Create user works as expected
@app.route('/user/<string:username>')
def create_user(username):
    new_user = user_datastore.create_user(username=username)
    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()
    print(new_user)

# When trying to create a thread record using the user object I receive an error message, when entering the integer of the user ID the record is successfully created
@app.route('/thread/<string:post>')


 def create_thread(post):
        user = User.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
        new_thread = Thread(title=post, user_id=user)
        db.session.add(new_thread)
        db.session.commit()
        print(new_thread)

    create_databse(app)
    return app


def create_databse(app):
    if os.path.isfile('database.db'):
        print('Database already created.')
    else:
        db.create_all(app=app)
        print('Database created.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

requirements.txt

```
autopep8==1.5.7
blinker==1.4
click==8.0.1
colorama==0.4.4
dnspython==2.1.0
email-validator==1.1.3
Flask==2.0.1
Flask-Login==0.5.0
Flask-Principal==0.4.0
Flask-Security-Too==4.1.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
Flask-WTF==0.15.1
greenlet==1.1.0
idna==3.2
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.1
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
passlib==1.7.4
pycodestyle==2.7.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.22
toml==0.10.2
Werkzeug==2.0.1
WTForms==2.3.3
```

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You must put user id in user_id not user object

```
new_thread = Thread(title=post, user_id=user.id)
```

And one more. You forgot to add fsqla.FsRoleMixin and fsqla.FsUserMixin to Parents of ur models Role and User like in quick start guide of Flask Security Too
https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#basic-sqlalchemy-application